# For a share’s price movement example, let E be the event that the share’s price

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For a share’s price movement example, let E be the event that the share’s price moved down exactly twice. Find, with a justification, the probability of E.

Where the sample space of share prices is

X= {uuu,uud,udd,udu,ddd,duu,ddu,dud}

Comment: There isn't enough information.  I take we are meant to assume that each move is independent of the others, yes?  But...Are we to assume that the probability of an up move is the same as the probability of a down move? That's an unusual assumption.

Comment: I think so. This is all the information I've been given @lulu

Comment: Well if the problem says "given three tosses of a fair coin, find the probability that you get exactly two Heads", you really should be able to do that on your own.